# Having troubles reading a txt file into R with columns delimited by ||

Tags: r

I'm having troubles trying to read a .txt file consisting of 561366 rows and 15 columns. The first rows look something like this:

```
  70000||Consumer A||23||DN||70000||10038782||1||SI||2||NO||0||N/A||0||N/A||1
  90000||Consumer B||23||DN||90000||15402432||1||SI||2||NO||0||N/A||0||N/A||1 
  .
  .
  .
```

The code I'm using for reading the file is:

```
  Datos <- read.table("C:/Users/hernandezn/Desktop/DataSets/INACTIVOS.txt", 
  header=FALSE, sep="|", na.strings="N/A", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
```

As you can see, my columns are separated by `"||"`, but I can't use it in the R command `read.table` as a`sep` option. So, I've used `sep="|"` and have to pay the price for that (now I have 29 columns).

The problem is that I'm just getting 241116 rows out of the  561366 I have in my file. On the other hand, I tried reading this file by replacing the `"||"` symbols by `;` and saving it as a .xlsx file and I'm getting all rows this way.

Could you suggest me a way to solve this problem? could it be a memory issue? I have a 32 bits R version running on a computer with 2GB of Memory Ram.

Comment: If there are no commas in your file maybe replace the '||' with ',' and keep the file as a *.txt file or change it to a *.csv file.

Comment: Is it getting the first 241116 rows? Or does it seem to be random? Are the line-end characters consistent?

Comment: I've found that the last lines of the 241116 rows file are the same of the original one @Spacedman. It's kind of random or something black I can't see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methinks the `sep=` character has to be of length one.  So you could simply call either an external command (like `sed` or `perl`) to substitute the two-character `||`, or do it yourself in R.

Here is a proof of concept one-liner that first switches the `||` to `,` (and as `|` is a meta character we need to escape it, and escape the escape character `\` too):

```
R> read.csv(textConnection(gsub("\\|\\|", ",", "70000||Consumer A||23||DN||70000||10038782||1||SI||2||NO||0||N/A||0||N/A||1\n90000||Consumer B||23||DN||90000||15402432||1||SI||2||NO||0||N/A||0||N/A||1")), header=FALSE)
     V1         V2 V3 V4    V5       V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15
1 70000 Consumer A 23 DN 70000 10038782  1 SI  2  NO   0 N/A   0 N/A   1
2 90000 Consumer B 23 DN 90000 15402432  1 SI  2  NO   0 N/A   0 N/A   1
R>
```

or maybe more legible in two lines:

```
R> txt <- "70000||Consumer A||23||DN||70000||10038782||1||SI||2||NO||0||N/A||0||N/A||1\n90000||Consumer B||23||DN||90000||15402432||1||SI||2||NO||0||N/A||0||N/A||1"
R> read.csv(textConnection(gsub("\\|\\|", ",", txt)), header=FALSE)
     V1         V2 V3 V4    V5       V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15
1 70000 Consumer A 23 DN 70000 10038782  1 SI  2  NO   0 N/A   0 N/A   1
2 90000 Consumer B 23 DN 90000 15402432  1 SI  2  NO   0 N/A   0 N/A   1
R>
```

Comment: Many thanks @Dirk Eddelbuettel, but how can I link my file into your solution?  ``read.csv(textConnection(gsub("\\|\\|", ",", txt)), header=FALSE)``? I appreciate your help.